# Microsoft.OData.ODataException-The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'tag' on type

Tags: odata, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a *get* endpoint request - *endpt{id}* which retrieves the table row based on the passed `integer` id. So by default all the columns are returned from the table.

- List item

I want to return only a subset of total columns of table. So, I am trying to use *`oData $select`*
I query as

```
{baseurl}/endpoint/3?$select=tag
```

where *Tag* is one of the column name.

In my startup.cs file, Confiure method , registered oData this way..
[image]

My Get Endpoint..

```
    [HttpGet]
    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("endpoint({id})")]
    [Route("endpt", Name = "endpt", Order = 0)]
    [Route("endpt/{id}", Name = "endpt", Order = 1)]        
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(APIResponseModel<List<EndPoints>>), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]      
    public APIResponseViewModel<List<EndPoints>> GetEndPoints(int limit, [FromODataUri] int id)
    {
        List<EndPoints> ListOfEndPoints;
        try
        {
            if (id.Equals(0))
            {
                ListOfEndPoints = db.EndPoints.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                ListOfEndPoints = db.EndPoints.Where(x => x.ID.Equals(id)).ToList();                    
            }               
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           //catch exp
        }

        if (limit == 0)
        {           

            this.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

            return new APIResponseModel<List<EndPoints>>
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Message = "Success",
                Result = ListOfEndPoints,
                Count = ListOfEndPoints.Count
            };
        }
        else
        {           

            this.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

            return new APIResponseModel<List<EndPoints>>
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Message = "Success",
                Result = ListOfEndPoints.Take(limit).ToList(),
                Count = ListOfEndPoints.Count
            };
        }
    }
```

Breakpoint hits, but in *`id`* I get only the *ID that I passed - 3*. select tag doesn't comes up, and from the implmented logic, it returns complete row matching that *id* with all the columns.

But at client side I recieve an error from oDataUriParser..

```
    {
    "Message": "The query specified in the URI is not valid. Could not find a property named 'tag' on type 'project'.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "Could not find a property named 'tag' on type 'Projects'.",
    "ExceptionType": "Microsoft.OData.ODataException",
    "StackTrace": "   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.SelectPathSegmentTokenBinder.ConvertNonTypeTokenToSegment(PathSegmentToken tokenIn, IEdmModel model, IEdmStructuredType edmType, ODataUriResolver resolver, BindingState state)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.SelectExpandBinder.ProcessSelectTokenPath(PathSegmentToken tokenIn)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.SelectExpandBinder.GenerateSelectItem(SelectTermToken tokenIn)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.SelectExpandBinder.Bind(ExpandToken expandToken, SelectToken selectToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.SelectExpandSemanticBinder.Bind(ODataPathInfo odataPathInfo, ExpandToken expandToken, SelectToken selectToken, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration, BindingState state)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseSelectAndExpandImplementation(String select, String expand, ODataUriParserConfiguration configuration, ODataPathInfo odataPathInfo)\r\n   at Microsoft.OData.UriParser.ODataQueryOptionParser.ParseSelectAndExpand()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.SelectExpandQueryOption.get_SelectExpandClause()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Validators.SelectExpandQueryValidator.Validate(SelectExpandQueryOption selectExpandQueryOption, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.SelectExpandQueryOption.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.Validators.ODataQueryValidator.Validate(ODataQueryOptions options, ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Query.ODataQueryOptions.Validate(ODataValidationSettings validationSettings)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ValidateQuery(HttpRequest request, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.CreateAndValidateQueryOptions(HttpRequest request, ODataQueryContext queryContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<OnActionExecuted>b__1(ODataQueryContext queryContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.ExecuteQuery(Object responseValue, IQueryable singleResultCollection, IWebApiActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, Func`2 modelFunction, IWebApiRequestMessage request, Func`2 createQueryOptionFunction)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNet.OData.EnableQueryAttribute.OnActionExecuted(Object responseValue, IQueryable singleResultCollection, IWebApiActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IWebApiRequestMessage request, Func`2 modelFunction, Func`2 createQueryOptionFunction, Action`1 createResponseAction, Action`3 createErrorAction)"
}
```

Please help me resolve this, as I don't see any complexity in my URL. but I am not able to find the missing point.

Thanks

Comment: I think this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515218/odata-error-the-query-specified-in-the-uri-is-not-valid-the-property-cannot-be) may be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might try changing this:

```
oDataBuilder.EntitySet<Endpoints>("Endpoints");
```

to this:

```
oDataBuilder.EntitySet<Endpoint>("Endpoints");
```

The idea being that your model is called `Endpoint` and your controller is called `Endpoints`.